# How to find/grep ethernet interface (en) from inet ip in Mac shell script

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, terminal

I want to grep or need result which ethernet interface "en" is getting inet ip.
In below `ifconfig` in terminal result `en6` is getting inet 192.188.10.111 so the result should be en6.

example: If `en2` or`en5` or any `en XxX` is getting inet IP id should show the ethernet interface enno.

It should not show  `lo0` loopback inet 127.0.0.1

```
MY_MAC:~ SKULL$ ifconfig

    lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
        options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
    stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
    en0: flags=8823<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 83:c1:9y:z0:g9:99 
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
        media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
        status: inactive
    en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
        ether 99:85:40:69:05:z0 
        media: autoselect <full-duplex>
        status: inactive
    en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
        ether 99:84:43:67:43:b6 
        media: autoselect <full-duplex>
        status: inactive
    p2p0: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
        ether 09:k5:6m:s6:q1:78 
        media: autoselect
        status: inactive
    awdl0: flags=8902<BROADCAST,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1452
        ether w1:6t:c3:w2:n4:78 
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
        media: autoselect
        status: inactive
    bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
        ether 23:j5:12:43:43:67 
        Configuration:
            id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
            maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
            root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
            ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
        member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
                ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
        member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
                ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
        media: <unknown type>
        status: inactive
    en6: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

        inet6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe36:550%en6 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
        inet 192.188.10.111 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.255.255
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
        media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
        status: active
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this meet your needs?

```
#!/bin/bash

for interface in `ifconfig | grep -v "\t" | awk -F':' '{print $1}'`; do
    if [ `ipconfig getifaddr $interface` ] ; then
        echo $interface
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you its working almost . But if i connect WIFI and ethernet Cable both same time it will show both results.  `en0` and `en5` as both getting IP.
`en0` is assigned for WIFI ethernet interface it will be good if we can remove `en0` from the result.